# Рекурсия в курсе Itvdn

Tags: java

Смотрю уроки от itvdn, дошел до рекурсии и застрял.

```
public class C05_MethodsRecursion {

    static void recursion(int counter) {
        counter--;

        System.out.println("Первая половина метода: " + counter);

        if (counter != 0)
            recursion(counter);

        System.out.println("Вторая половина метода: " + counter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recursion(3);
    }
}
```

Если запустить то выводит так 2 1 0 0 1 2. Я не очень понимаю как выполняется вторая половина метода

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно? Сформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Поработай интерпретатором явы и все станет понятно. Выполни эту функцию вручную на бумажке

Comment: Как метод выводит 0 1 2? Как выводятся 2 1 0 понятно

Comment: "**как** метод выводит `0 1 2`" - с помощью `System.out.println`. "**Почему** метод выводит `0 1 2`" - потому что значение параметра метода `counter` равно `0`, `1` и `2` соответственно. Быть может, ваш вопрос на самом деле про то, почему выводится `0 1 2`, а не `0 0 0`. А, может, почему `0 1 2`, а не `2 1 0`. В общем, сформулируйте вопрос чётко.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вторая часть кажого вызова метода будет выполнена только после того как будут выполнены все первые части метода. А они будут выполняться до тех пор пока `counter` не `0`.

Т.е.

```
counter=2; //метод вызван впервые, условие срабатывает и метод запускает сам себя не исполнившись до конца

   counter=1; //второй вызов метода, условие срабатывает и метод запускает сам себя не исполнившись до конца

      counter=0; //тут не срабатывает условие и выполняется вторая часть метода
      counter=0;

   counter=1; //завершается вторая половина второго вызова метода

counter=2; //завершается вторая половина первого вызова метода
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Первая половина метода: " + 2);
    System.out.println("Первая половина метода: " + 1);
      System.out.println("Первая половина метода: " + 0);
      System.out.println("Первая половина метода: " + 0);
    System.out.println("Первая половина метода: " + 1);    
System.out.println("Первая половина метода: " + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Система запоминает значение counter для каждого цикла и помещает его в стек, принцип которого "last in first out". Поэтому вторая часть метода отрабатывается для всех значений counter с обратной последовательностью.